# Show that the full k-shift is totally disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, ergodic-theory

Reading from Walkden's lecture notes on Ergodic Theory (https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/lecture03.pdf), in the first two paragraphs of page 6 (i.e. §3.4.3 Bernoulli and Markov measures) it is claimed the following three:

1- Cylinders are open subsets of $\Sigma_k$.
2- Cylinders are closed subsets of $\Sigma_k$.
3- "1" and "2" above reflects the fact that $\Sigma_k$ is totally disconnected.

I want to prove those three claims:

1- Consider some a cylinder $U=[i_0, ..., i_n]_m$ and a point x \in U, say $(..., i_0, ..., i_n, x_0, x_1, ...)$ (Here I consider $\Sigma_k^+$ the full one-sided k-shift. The set of all points $(i_0, ..., i_n, y, x_1, ...)$ for all possible $y$ is an open set containing $x$ since it is a "neighborhood" of $x$ and its intersection with complement of $U$ in $\Sigma_k$ is empty. So $U$ is open and so is $\Sigma_k$. Is my argument correct?

2- Consider the same $U$ and $x$ in Item "1" above. The sequence of points $(..., i_0, ..., i_n, y_0, y_1, ...)$ such that if $y_0=x_0$ then we go on until we arrive at $y_k \ne x_k$ then we decrease or increase $y_k$ to be equal to $x_k$ and each step is a sequence in the sequences that the limit approaches $x$. So $\Sigma_k$ is closed. Is my argument correct?

3- According to the Wiki the singletons are the only connected proper subsets in a totally disconnected space. How is this related to every set being clopen?

Comment: Please [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671)

Comment: @LeeMosher this is a one question